# MongoDB error when i run this code it gives me that error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

the error in my editor:

D:\MEAN\app\models\user.js:1

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Schema' of undefined
> at Object. (D:\MEAN\app\models\user.js:1:25)
> at Module._compile (node:interna

```js
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
// const { Schema } = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

And make sure `mongoose` is installed if not :

```
npm install mongoose --save
```